# Mesos offer.getExecutorIdsList gives an empty list though UI shows executors

Tags: mesos

I am trying to check mesos offers for agents which already are running any tasks from my framework.
I am using offer.getExecutorIdsList which, according to mesos documentation, is supposed to return all executors that belong to same framework.
But all i get is an empty list though i can see the executors in mesos UI.
Is there something that i need to enable to get this info about executors ?